# Strange behavior in carmine (clojure-redis client)

Tags: clojure, redis, carmine

Consider this snippet in carmine

```
(wcar* (car/set "counter" 1)            ;; expect to be number counter=1
       (let [id (car/get "counter")]    ;; expect to have id=1
         (println id)))                 ;; [nil [[SET counter 1] [GET counter]]]
```

What I am doing wrong here? Is there a way to use `let` inside `wcar*` macro?

Answer (score 1):

You can nest `wcar` forms which gives you access to the return values inside `wcar`:

```
(wcar*
  (car/set "counter" 1)
  (let [id (wcar*
             (car/get "counter"))]
    (println id)
    id))
```

Comment: The problem is `id` is not desired value of `1` but vector `[nil [[SET counter 1] [GET counter]]]` instead

Comment: Oh, I see now! I've changed my answer to reflect what you're actually asking ;)